# Refreshing RealmList after transactions - Android

Tags: android, database, realm

I am using Realm in my android app.

I do the following after receiving after parsing Json and receiving a RealmObject called ***MessageList*** from my backend.

```
    if (messageList != null) {
        RealmList<Message> messages = messageList.getItems();
        if (messages.size() > 0) {

            //Populate Recycler view UI
            displayMessages(messages);

            //Start transaction
            dbManager.copyToRealm(messages);
            //End transaction....
        }
    }



public void displayMessages(RealmList<Message> messages) {
    mAdapter = new EventsAdapter(getContext(), mPresenter, messages,
            mPolentaApi.getCommunity());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

***Message*** is a RealmObject as well.

I can modify a Message in another area of my app and I need these changes to be reflected in my UI.

Here is my adapter:

```
public MessageAdapter(Context context, RealmList<Message> messages){
}
```

I've tried using notifyDataSetChanged() with my adapter but it doesn't work.

I'm aware of RealmBaseAdapter but this is only available with RealmResults https://realm.io/docs/java/0.85.1/api/io/realm/RealmBaseAdapter.html

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the copied messages to the adapter. Realm does not modify the original ones, but instead return the managed copy, where changes will be reflected: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/Realm.html#copyToRealm-E-

If you want show the messages that are automatically updated you have to do something like this:

`List<Message> managedMessages = dbManager.copyToRealm(message);
new MessageAdapter(context, managedMessages);`

Comment: I'm already doing that, please see the displayMessages method above

Comment: It doesn't look that way. You are calling `displayMessage()` before doing `copyToRealm()` which means you are showing the non-copied values in the UI.